# How to merge list of lists of JS objects to one JS object list

Tags: javascript, json

i have a below JSON with 4 fields where 4th one is list of js objects

```
[
  {
    "srNumber": 1,
    "Name": "prod name",
    "includeInAutoSupplies": true,
    "childObjectList": [
      {
        "cValue": "cValue Name 1",
        "Name": "testName1",
      },
      {
        "cValue": "cValue Name 2",
        "Name": "testName2",
      },
      {
        "cValue": "cValue Name 3",
        "Name": "testName3",
      },
    ]
  }
]
```

It is difficult to explain in words here but I need to convert the above array to the one shown in the below, where  testName1, 2, 3 are the value of Name of child object's field and cValue Name1, 2, 3 are the values of cValue in child object array.

```
[
  {
    "srNumber": 1,
    "Name": "prod name",
    "includeInAutoSupplies": true,
    "testName1": "cValue Name 1"
    "testName2": "cValue Name 2"
    "testName3": "cValue Name 3"
  }
]
```

I cannot change the JSON structure as this is how I am getting it, and I need to make this as one array of objects instead array of arrays property in it so that I can further use it to export into .csv file.

Comment: what you've tried so far ? post the code

Comment: @CodeManiac, I am sorry I didn't post my unsuccessful attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Functional approach:**

```js
const transform = list => list.map(
  entry => Object.fromEntries([
    ...Object.entries(entry).filter(([k]) => k !== 'childObjectList'),
    ...entry.childObjectList.map(({ Name, cValue }) => [Name, cValue])
  ])
)
```

Explanation: [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) returns an array `[[k1, v1], [k2, v2]]` from `{ k1: v1, k2: v2 }` and [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) does the opposite. This way, we map all entries in your list to their transformed selves, consisting of a combination of all existing properties except `childObjectList` and the contents of `childObjectList` converted to separate properties.

---

**Imperative approach:**

```js
function transform (list) {
  for (const entry of list) {
    for (const { Name, cValue } of entry.childObjectList) {
      entry[Name] = cValue
    }
    delete entry.childObjectList
  }
  return list
}
```

Note that this one mutates `list` and its children. If this is undesired, you could change it like this:

```js
function transform (list) {
  const newList = []
  for (const { ...entry } of list) {
    for (const { Name, cValue } of entry.childObjectList) {
      entry[Name] = cValue
    }
    delete entry.childObjectList
    newList.push(entry)
  }
  return newList
}
```

Explanation: We simply loop over the elements in your list and modify them (or create modified copies) in such a way that the `childObjectList` property is removed and instead each child is added as separate property.

---

In all three cases, if you then call `transform(theArray)`, you get your desired result.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help but above approaches doesn't permit duplicate keys, would you please provide a solution where I can use duplicate keys as well

Comment: Sorry but that's not possible, objects cannot have duplicate keys (otherwise how would the computer know which `y` you mean when you write `x.y`?). You need to rethink your desired output format then.

Comment: so there no other way we can achieve the same to have duplicate keys

Comment: Exactly. I think the original format you already have is the most optimal one in that case, so the whole transformation is the wrong direction. You can just use the `filter` function to access properties and get an array with all matching ones, like `obj.childObjectList.filter(o => o.Name === 'testName1').map(o => o.cValue)` which gives `['cValue Name 1']`